# Why is my code not getting assigned to my div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Wordle clone for class and I've followed a tut but it still isn't working. In the tutorial, the buttons are assigned under the "key-container" div (see here https://youtu.be/mpby4HiElek?t=971) but it will not work for me. I suspect that it has something to do with the script.js part. This is the code I've written and I would appreciate help! Thanks in advance!

```js
const tileDisplay = document.querySelector('.tile-container')
const keyboard = document.querySelector('.key-container')

const keys = [
    'Q',
    'W',
    'E',
    'R',
    'T',
    'Y',
    'U',
    'I',
    'O',
    'P',
    'A',
    'S',
    'D',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'J',
    'K',
    'L',
    'ENTER',
    'Z',
    'X',
    'C',
    'V',
    'B',
    'N',
    'M',
    '«',
]
const guessRows = [
  ['', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', '']
]

guessRows.forEach((guessRow,guessRowIndex) => {
  const rowElement = document.createElement('div') 
  rowElement.setAttribute('id', 'guessRow-' + guessRowIndex)
  tileDisplay.append(rowElement)
}) 

const handleClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked')
}

keys.forEach(key => {
  const buttonElement = document.createElement('button')
  buttonElement.textContent = key
  buttonElement.setAttribute('id', key)
  buttonElement.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
  keyboard.append(buttonElement)
})
```

```css
     {
  color:#ffffff;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Times New Roman', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #212121
}
.game-container {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-container {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  width: 510px; 
  border-bottom: solid 4px #49494b; 
}

.tile-container {
  width: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.key-container {
  width: 530px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.key-container button {
  width: 43px;
  height: 58px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #818389;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px;
}

.key-container button:nth-child(11) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.key-container button:nth-child(20),
.key-container button:nth-child(28) {
  width: 68px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wordle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
    <body>

        <div class="game-container">
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1>Wordle</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="message-container"></div>
            <div class="tile-container"></div>
            <div class="key-container"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, to start, you have; `<script src="app.js"></script>` but in your question you say `script.js` - which is not refenced in your HTML

Comment: The code itself works fine, with the above comment explaining why in _your_ case things are going wrong. However, on a modern HTML note: stick that script element in your `<head>` element, but make to load it async, and deferred: `<script src="script.js" async defer></script>`. This will load it in parallel without blocking, and will _run_ the code only after the document has been parsed.

Comment: I dont get it what's wrong exactly?

Comment: _I dont get it what's wrong exactly?_ If you look at the first comment by Can O' Spam, they point it out-- you state you have called your JS file `script.js`, but in your code your are importing a file called `app.js`.  Can O' Spam is surmising that the `<script/>` tag is looking for `app.js`, `404`ing because no such file exists (because it is actually called `script.js`), and thus none of your JS is actually being executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was as all of you mentioned that I was sourcing from app.js and not script.js. A very dumb and easily fixed mistake on my part. Thank all of you though for the help!